# android: ImageView fadingEdge not work

Tags: android, imageview, fading

I have an ImageView in my app and the fading Effect of the image view not work here is my imageView

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/prevImageview"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.61"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/landscape_" />
```

but i can't see any fading effect.
can anyone tell me what is the solution?
Thanks

Comment: What type of effect you are applying to your imageview

Comment: I want to see fading effect on image border

Comment: But what kind of fading effect like, fade in, fade out, bounce, rotation, etc...

Comment: try below code and let me know whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Okay try to use below code.

Create XML called **fadein.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

and then add this to your image-view

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/prevImageview"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    style="@drawable/fadein"
    android:src="@drawable/landscape_" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but i can't see any fading effect yet

Comment: I think it's because of less time you are not able to see effect, increase the time in duration like `android:duration="1000"` with `android:duration="5000"`. and try

Comment: I have a question: what mean the duration? i just want static fading effect on image border like this:
http://www.filterforge.com/filters/11330.jpg

Comment: I try that with android:duration="10000" but this does not work